# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.coco_utils' utils' is not a package

Tags: python, module, google-colaboratory

I'm using Colab for the first time and trying to run a project and got this error .. i tried to

```
!pip install utils.coco_utils
```

but got the same error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.coco_utils'; 'utils' is not a package
```

Comment: Have you tried: `'pip3 install utils'`? If that does not work try using 'pip3 uninstall utils' then try the first command to get the latest version as that may be the one that includes coco_utils.

Comment: i got Requirement already satisfied: utils in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.0.1)

Comment: Use the commands I provided to uninstall then reinstall the package.

Comment: If the error persists try: 'pip3 install coco_utils'. If that does not work then I unfortunately can not answer your question.

Comment: thanks for helping but i got when `pip3 uninstall utils` then install it again ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.coco_utils'; 'utils' is not a package

Comment: If utils is not a package then coco_utils must be and just run the same commands except with 'coco_utils'

Comment: You need to add more context to these packages or modules so people can understand what they are.

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to use **coco_utils** from [vision/references/detection/](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/references/detection).
Just copy it into folder with your .ipynb file and import as a module.